# XML difference using maven

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have a requirement to find out the differences between XML files of the current release and previous release, and report the differences in HTML format. These XML files are packaged in a jar during the build of their modules (in Maven), and are stored in our repository. 
I need to find and report differences during this Maven build process, and hence I am looking for a Maven plugin. 
I found similar questions at the these links - [Ques1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617785/compare-xml-files-with-maven-or-ant) and [Ques2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375279/is-there-a-maven-plugin-that-can-diff-files-and-output-the-result-to-file) - but these are pretty old, and I was wondering if we have something latest.

Is writing a maven plugin with [XMLUnit](https://www.xmlunit.org/) the best way to go with this? Do we already have any maven plugins?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions looking for software recommendations are off-topic. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/